# While loop file rename in PHP

Tags: php

i am trying to rename the file with $n if the file name is already exists in PHP. Please let me know where i am wrong.

```
if ( file_exists( $uploadfilename ) ) {
    $uploadfilebasename = basename( $uploadfilename );
    $path_parts = pathinfo( $uploadfilebasename );
    $n = 1;
    $path_update = $path_parts['filename'].$n.'.'.$path_parts['extension'];
    $uploadfilename = $uploaddir. basename( $path_update );
    while ( file_exists( $uploadfilename ) ) {
        $path_update = $path_parts['filename'].$n.'.'.$path_parts['extension'];
        $n++;
    }
    echo $path_update;
}
```

Please Suggest a solution if i want to check upto only 10 times otherwise it will throw an error "File upload limit exceeds".

Thank you

Comment: *Please let me know where i am wrong.* - what it is symptoms of 'wrong'?

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry, i was just doing stupid. Problem solved.

```
while(file_exists($uploadfilename)){
  $path_update= $path_parts['filename'].$n.'.'.$path_parts['extension'];
  $uploadfilename = $uploaddir. basename($path_update);
  $n++;
}
echo $path_update;
```